# I am trying to pull IAM user, role it assumes, permissions attached to the role through python script

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to pull IAM user, role it assumes, permissions attached to the role through python script. I am very new to both Python and AWS. Can someone please guide me in the right direction. IAM for a given account.  Looking for:

- A list of principles present
- A list of roles/policies that relate to each principle
- Creation date against each principle, last access date, console
- Trusted Account relationships
- Federated access enabled on the account

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Some resources you can use:

- [AWS Identity and Access Management User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html)
- [AWS IAM API Reference Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)
- [IAM — Boto 3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html)

If you have a problem with a specific API call, feel free to create a question with the code you are using and the issue you are facing.